# Read all txt files in a specific folder and write all contents in one txt file

Tags: php, file

I try to read all `*.txt` files from a folder and write all content from each file into another txt file. But somehow it only writes one line into the txt file.

I tried with `fwrite()` and `file_put_contents()`, neither worked.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    $dh = opendir('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/');

    while($file = readdir($dh)) {
        $contents = file_get_contents('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/' . $file);
        $dc = array($contents);   
    }

    file_put_contents('content.txt', $dc);

?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I get all *.txt files in a directory with [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). After this I loop through every file with a foreach loop and get the content of each single file with [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and I put the content into the target file with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php))

```
<?php

    $files = glob("path/*.txt");
    $output = "result.txt";

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $content = file_get_contents($file);
        file_put_contents($output, $content, FILE_APPEND);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just tried your code, the $content contains all files content, but for some reason, it only writes the last file's content into the result.txt file

Comment: @user3345164 Did you copied my **exact** code? Also make sure the flag `FILE_APPEND` is in `file_put_contents()` so that it actually appends the content.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I tried re-copy your whole code, it actually create an empty result.txt file, but if I remove the FILE_APPEND, it create a result.txt file with the last file content

Comment: @user3345164 It should work. Make sure your path in `glob()` is right! Also do `print_r($files);` before the foreach loop to see which files there are.

Comment: Yep, your code actually get all contents properly, but for some reason, it only write the last file's content into the result.txt if I take out the FILE_APPEND, with the FILE_APPEND, it won't write anything into the result.txt file, could that something to do with the txt files formate?

Comment: @user3345164  What txt format do you use/have? Also maybe try use this line: `file_put_contents($output, $content, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);` Here I added an additional flag, so that the file is locked while you write in it. (If it still doesn't work, try to create 2 txt files with content like: `abc` and `def` and try it with these 2 test files)

Comment: I think that's something to do with MAC's txt formate, i just tried on Windows environment, which working perfectly! Thanks for your help very much!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$contents = array();
$line = file(/*next file in dir*/);
foreach($lines as line){
   array_push($line, $contents);
}
//File path of final result
    $filepath = "mergedfiles.txt";

    $out = fopen($filepath, "w");
    //Then cycle through the files reading and writing.

      foreach($filepathsArray as $file){
          $in = fopen($file, "r");
          while ($line = fgets($in)){
                print $file;
               fwrite($out, $line);
          }
          fclose($in);
      }

    //Then clean up
    fclose($out);

    return $filepath;
```